# How do I connect Apache spark with a website to display result?

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, backend, vs-web-site-project

I want to build a website which will take an input file and process it on Apache spark in the backend then send back the output to website.
I am not understanding how to connect spark running on Jupyter notebook with my website.
Any idea is highly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Spark won’t communicate directly with your web application servers, really. One possible way around this is to publish your results to a database (MongoDB or PostgreSQL, for instance) and then integrate it with your website.

Comment: Thanks Dave Canton.What about spark job server and apache livy aren't they helpful ??

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer regarding the question.
I have used python flask code in my pyspark program and it is giving me desired result on website.